# Websocket 404 when proxy_pass through 2 nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, proxypass

I'm trying to get websockets (socket.io) to work through 2 proxy_pass and 2 different servers (one is a server loadbalancer, the another one is the actual server). I get an 400 when the socket.io is trying

In this case, I have two servers, 1 domainName :

domainName : dev-socket.domain.com -> cname to lb.domain.com

Server 1 : lb.domain.com
- handling all the certifications
- handling all our {subdomain}.domain.com requests, proxy_pass them to the rightfull servers 
- everything works fine, except websockets

Server 2 : dev.domain.com
- host the actual api handling all the websockets
- nginx proxyPass to rightfull :port application

What should work, and doesn't :

dev-socket.domain.com (domainName) -> lb.domain.com (Server1, ssl) -> dev.domain.com (server2) -> nodeJsApp

This is getting an 400.

WHAT WORKS : this works, if I bypass the lb.domain.com and directly do this : 
dev-socket.domain.com (domainName) -> dev.domain.com (server2, ssl) -> nodeJsApp

server 1 : lb.domain.com :

```
map $http_connection $upgrade_requested {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dev-socket.domain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.domain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.domain.com-error.log error;

    client_max_body_size 256M;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev- 
    socket.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev- 
    socket.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    includeSubDomains; preload";

    location /socket/live {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;    
    proxy_pass http://91.121.117.17/socket/live;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server_dev;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }


    location ~ ^/.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }
}
```

server 2 : dev.domain.com

```
map $http_connection $upgrade_requested { 
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen *:443;
    server_name dev-socket.domain.com;

        #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-socket.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-socket.domain.com/privkey.pem;
        #ssl on;

        client_max_body_size 5M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.domain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.error;

    location /socket/live {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name dev-socket.domain.com;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.domain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-socket.error;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

the above configuration gets a simple 400 error during the handshake instead of succeeding.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://dev-socket.domain.com/socket/live/?Auth=e02b7a2ab5c158d7f46c18d36f45955bf3769716&sessionId=5a38e191fc6bf8602001b237&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Fu6M2b1I9sh9stLFAANX' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I can confirm by checking the activty logs of both nginx (server1, server2) that the request is getting to server2. So my guess for the moment is something about a malformed header..

As a said, if I bypass lb.domain.com, and activate ssl on the dev.domain.com direclty, it is working

Comment: I realise it might be a bit harsh to understand what I described one week ago, if someone might need some further details, it would be a great help to me =)

Comment: I have occured the same question. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: hello, unfornately no, I had to pass-by my loadbalancer (and have only one nginx proxy pass) to get my solution working.